# How can I get the value of +IPD response

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

The problem is the value of +IPD response isn't show up at the ReadLastEntryThingSpeak(), so my code isn't correct or I must add something? I have searched for many websites Arduino forum, Thingspeak forum, and others. But I didn't see any solution. :(

I have tried to do this system for 5 days and it doesn't work, why?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h>

#define esp8266 Serial1

#define SSID "test"    // put here the name of your wifi network
#define PASS "lolman123"    
#define IP "184.106.153.149"

int counter = 120;
String keep;
String valuetosend;

const byte maxDataLength = 30;  // maxDataLength is the maximum length 
allowed for received data.
char receivedChars[31] ;        
boolean newData = false;

String GET = "GET /update?key=FYPW04TOYR3FX2QH&";    // put here your 
thingspeak key
String GET1 = "field1=";

String readGET1 = "GET 
https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/864152/fields/1/last";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  esp8266.println("AT");
  delay(5000);
  if(esp8266.find("OK")){
  connectWiFi();
  Serial.println("WIFI CONNECTED");
}
pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
newData = false;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int readBtn = digitalRead(7);
  int readSend = digitalRead(8); 

  if (readBtn == 0)
  {
    ReadLastEntryThingSpeak();
  }

  if (readSend == 0)
  {
    WriteThingSpeak();
  }
}

boolean connectWiFi(){
  esp8266.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  delay(2000);
  String cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"";
  cmd+=SSID;
  cmd+="\",\"";
  cmd+=PASS;
  cmd+="\"";
  esp8266.println(cmd);
  delay(5000);
  if(esp8266.find("OK")){
    Serial.println("OK");
    return true;
  }else{
    Serial.println("KO");
    return false;
  }
}

void updateFunction(String valuetosend){
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += IP;
  cmd += "\",80";
  esp8266.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);
  if(esp8266.find("Error")){
    Serial.print("Error1");
    return;
  }
  cmd = GET + GET1;
  cmd += valuetosend;
  cmd += "\r\n";
  Serial.print(cmd);
  esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
  esp8266.println(cmd.length());
  if(esp8266.find(">")){
    esp8266.print(cmd);
  }else{
    esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  }
}

void ReadLastEntryThingSpeak()
{
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\""; //connect to thingspeak
  cmd += IP;
  cmd += "\",80";
  esp8266.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);
  if(esp8266.find("Error")){
    Serial.print("Error1");
    return;
  }
  cmd = readGET1;
  cmd += "\r\n";
  Serial.print(cmd);
  esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND="); 
  esp8266.println(cmd.length());
  if(esp8266.find(">")){
    esp8266.print(cmd);
  }else{
    esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  }
  delay(2000);
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();                // check to see if we have 
  received any new commands
  if (newData)  {   processCommand();  }
}

void WriteThingSpeak ()
{
    String valuetosend = String(counter);
    updateFunction(valuetosend);
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() 
{
     static boolean recvInProgress = false;
     static byte ndx = 0;
     char startMarker = ':';
 char endMarker = 'C';

 if (esp8266.available() > 0) 
 {
      char rc = esp8266.read();
      if (recvInProgress == true) 
      {
           if (rc != endMarker) 
           {
                    if (ndx < maxDataLength) { receivedChars[ndx] = rc; 
ndx++;      }
               }
               else 
               {
                     receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                     recvInProgress = false;
                     ndx = 0;
                     newData = true;
               }
          }
          else if (rc == startMarker) { recvInProgress = true; }
     }

}

void processCommand()
{
   Serial.print("Recieved data = ");   Serial.println(receivedChars);
   newData = false;
}
```

I have the result of Received data = , but the actual output is Received data =  120.

Comment: I don't know what the value of +IPD response is, so will most of us. name the function where you observe that problem, explain what that +IPD response looks like so everyone who knows Arduino/C++ well can help

Comment: +IPD,3:120CLOSED it responses like this.